# Energy convertion

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Why cannot light energy and sound energy be interchanged? Why is energy converted always in kinetic? Why cannot potential energy be converted from one form to the other when energy is in mechanical form? Can a body have both kinetic and potential energy? Why does the principle of conservation of energy not hold true in fusion or fission?

Comment: "*Why is energy converted always in kinetic*" It is not; why would you assume so? "*Can a body have both kinetic and potential energy?*" Sure, why not? "*Why does the principle of conservation of energy not hold true in fusion or fission?*" It certainly does, why wouldn't it? Sir, if you detail the questions a bit more, you might get much better answers.

Comment: "Why cannot light energy and sound energy be interchanged?" They can: [somoluminiscense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence)

Comment: I didnt know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why cannot light energy and sound energy be interchanged?

Because they are nothing *whatsoever* alike.

I know what you're thinking, "but wait, light is a wave, and sound is a wave..." Ask this key question, "what is a wave?". A wave, in classical terms, is not "a thing". It is simply motion of some other thing. Water waves are just water moving. Waves in traffic are cars moving. Sound waves are air (etc.) molecules moving.

Light is not a wave. We used to think it was because it had behaviours we saw in other waves, so we simply concluded it was a wave. It wasn't. It's much more like a particle, although that's not quite right either. In any event, it's not "a wave".

So although it's not clear at first glance, you are really asking why you can't turn one thing into another. For instance, "why can't you turn cars into water? Both can have waves..." In that case the answer is obvious, right? And as long as you know that light is not a wave, then the answer is obvious there too.

> Why does the principle of conservation of energy not hold true in
>   fusion or fission?

It does. E=mc^2. The resulting helium from fusion is slightly lighter than the original hydrogens.